# Tracking/analytics scoped to an embedded JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, azure-application-insights

We are developing a JavaScript script which others can embed into their web sites by linking the script via a `<script>` tag.

We would like to monitor the script for stability issues, performance and feature usage. As the script will run under the context of third-party sites, we do not have access to the analytics of the hosting page.

- How do you recommend to monitor the stability, performance and usage of our embeddable JavaScript component?
- It is possible to set up Application Insights, Google Analytics etc. such that the site owners get theirs default instance as usual while we fire up our (local) instance scoped to track just our script?

Answer (score -1):

This is a tricky question.

First of all, I think you should inform your client that you would like to send this kind of information, and maybe allow them to opt-out that behaviour (in rare cases where bandwidth usage is restricted for example, or GDPR/security compliance, etc..)

I think you should also fire very minimalist calls not too often too, to have a minimal fingerprint on end-user side. Maybe small GET calls to a specific url of yours with some query arg parameters and an 200 ok response no matter what, very fast. Use queue messaging on your side (RabbitMQ) to stack these "monitoring calls" and answer as quickly as possible.

Then do what you want on your side when unstacking these events, send them to your database, to a 3rd party provider like semgent.io or google analytics. Do not store personal data, only anonymised info.

Best

Comment: Thanks for a great checklist what to keep on mind when building custom tracking. I prefer to use an existing service like Application Insights before building the tracking and reporting inhouse.

Comment: Ok, I just read the Azure Application Insights documentation and it is pretty neat. They tend to have a minimalist impact, batch events and send them in an async and non blocking way, that I described above :)